# Write AuthContext.js in a separate file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-context

I have written AuthContext.js in a seprate file like bellow

```
export const AuthContext = createContext({
  isLoggedIn: false,
  login: () => {},
  logout: () => {},
});
 
const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
 
  const loginHandler = useCallback(() => {
    setIsLoggedIn(true);
  }, []);
 
  const logoutHandler = useCallback(() => {
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
  }, []);
 
  const initialValue = {
    isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
    login: loginHandler,
    logout: logoutHandler,
  };
 
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={initialValue}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>;
  );
};
 
export default AuthContextProvider;
```

Then I import them manually in `App.js`

I recognized that when do I login, `App.js` never re-render even the value of `isLoggedIn` changed.

Result in `routes` variable never gotten new values, components will not change as well.

The App.js file

```
const App = () => {
  const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { isLoggedIn } = authCtx;
  let routes;
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Users />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/places/new" exact>
          <NewPlace />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/:userId/places" exact>
          <UserPlaces />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/places/:placeId">
          <UpdatePlace />
        </Route>
 
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    );
  } 
  else {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Users />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/:userId/places" exact>
          <UserPlaces />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/signin" exact>
          <SignIn />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/signup" exact>
          <Signup />
        </Route>
        <Redirect to="/signin" />
      </Switch>
    );
  }

  return (
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <MainNavigation />
        <main>{routes}</main>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AuthContextProvider>
  );
};
 
export default App;
```

What is my mistake in this case.

Comment: What is the value of the `const authCtx = useContext(AuthContext);`? Asking because usually you want to put the component, that uses the context `inside`, as a `children` of the `<AuthContextProvider>` in your case.

Comment: I initialize it with data to get better auto-completion. Am not sure what u mean

Comment: I mean that you need to put `<App />` component inside of the `<AuthContextProvider>...</AuthContextProvider>` as a children dom element, to make App actually see the `context` that is provided by AuthContextProvider.

Comment: Ok I see, I will try in index.js file, wrap <App/> in <AuthContextProvider>..</AuthContextProvider>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `App` is the component rendering the `AuthContextProvider` component then it can't access the Context value it provides. The `AuthContextProvider` must be rendered higher in the ReactTree in order for `App` to be able to access the Context value. Current `App` is receiving the default value that was passed to `React.createContext`.

```
export const AuthContext = createContext({
  isLoggedIn: false,
  login: () => {},
  logout: () => {},
});
```

The default value is used when there is not any Context provider higher in the ReactTree.

Move `AuthContextProvider` to be higher in the ReactTree, i.e. wrap `App`.

App

```
const App = () => {
  const { isLoggedIn } = useContext(AuthContext);

  let routes;

  if (isLoggedIn) {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Users />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/places/new" exact>
          <NewPlace />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/:userId/places" exact>
          <UserPlaces />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/places/:placeId">
          <UpdatePlace />
        </Route>
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    );
  } 
  else {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Users />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/:userId/places" exact>
          <UserPlaces />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/signin" exact>
          <SignIn />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/signup" exact>
          <Signup />
        </Route>
        <Redirect to="/signin" />
      </Switch>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <MainNavigation />
      <main>{routes}</main>
    </>
  );
};
 
export default App;
```

```
<AuthContextProvider>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
</AuthContextProvider>
```